# connecting to server with haskell

Tags: haskell

Suppose in my program I need to connect to the server (using only `Network`, not `Network.Socket`!) and `post`, `get` some data (think about it as `telnet` analog). I need to receive messages from server in separate  thread (because I can send something on server and get something seperatly). So the question is how to receive messages and and send it in two separate threads? I dont know how to use `forkIO` and how to use `Handle`

For now I wrote something like this:

```
sender :: Handle -> IO ()
sender h = do
    toSend <- getContents
    hPutStr h toSend
    sender h

receiver :: Handle -> IO ()
receiver h = do
    response <- hGetContents h
    putStrLn $ "the response is: " ++ response
    receiver h

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let host = "haskell.org"
    let port = 40
    h <- connectTo host (PortNumber $ fromIntegral i)
    forkIO $ receiver h
    sender h
    return ()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood, this code works quite well. The main problem was with port I used. `haskell.org`'s port 40 is not open (found out using `nmap`). So the connection just freezed. Only few changes I did in sender and receiver:

```
sender :: Handle -> IO ()
sender h = getContents >>= hPutStrLn h

receiver :: Handle -> IO ()
receiver h = hGetContents h >>= putStrLn
```

So the final code is

```
import Network
import Control.Concurrent(forkIO)
import System.IO
import System.Environment
import Control.Monad

sender :: Handle -> IO ()
sender h = getContents >>= hPutStrLn h

receiver :: Handle -> IO ()
receiver h = forever $ hGetLine h >>= putStrLn 

main :: IO ()
main = do
    [host, port] <- getArgs
    h <- connectTo host (Service port)
    forkIO $ receiver h
    sender h
    return ()
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? As your sender function does not loop, it will not actually be like telnet. And why wouldn't you use sockets? Did you have a look at [the chat server example](https://wiki.haskell.org/Implement_a_chat_server) on the haskell wiki? Oh, and by the way, it's considered bad ettiquette just blindly using some server for testing.

Comment: @JanGreve you can try it. It will be exactly like telnet. No need of loop here. Every time you press enter `getContents` will work. And in `receive` I have `forever`

Comment: I see. I did somewhat oversee the suble lazy IO that is implied here. Not quite as verbose as I expected is to be from the rest of your code. My bad.